# how to enable gzip compression when using https?

Tags: nginx, gzip, deflate

**how to enable gzip compression when using https?**

how to enable gzip compression when using https?

I used a tool at http://checkgzipcompression.com/ to verify this and me says:
"GZIP is not enabled :(
By compressing this page with GZIP, 66.7% bandwidth could be saved." and curl shows the same results.

Details below:

> curl -I -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate' HTTP://..

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx
Date: Wed, 24 Jun 2015 02:00:34 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Content-Length: 20
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

> curl -I -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate' HTTPS://..

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Wed, 24 Jun 2015 02:00:41 GMT
Content-Type: text/css
Content-Length: 4778
Last-Modified: Sun, 21 Jun 2015 16:54:59 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
ETag: "5586ec63-12aa"
Expires: Thu, 31 Dec 2037 23:55:55 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=315360000
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

Comment: Is your server configured to support GZIP? Your client can ask for it, but the server doesn't need to honor it.

Comment: Directive `gzip on` is default config. If you removed it, then just put it back